# Trouble putting data into global variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scope, global-variables

I have several method implementations that need access to the same variables. For example, I have a variable that I am placing a user's first name in, and I need to be able to access this variable in all of my various method implementations inside the same View Controller.

I have created a custom class called "PotentialFriend" which is a subclass of NSObject. PotentialFriend's header file also contains an NSString property called "name".

In my view controller's header file I have created an instance of my PotentialFriend class called "potentialFriend". I can successfully type "_potentialFriend.name" in the View Controller's main file, but if I set it to equal something like @"Steve" it shows as (null) in the console.

However, if I do the following, and actually initialize a local variable, I can successfully get the variable to hold the data:

```
PotentialFriend *potentialFriend = [[PotentialFriend alloc]init];

potentialFriend.name = @"Steve";
```

But this doesn't work for me because I have another method implementation in this VC that sets up the UITableView's settings and I need to be able to access the value of "potentialFriend.name".

The only way I know how to do this is with global variables, but like I said I can't get the global variables to actually hold the data.

Any ideas why I can't get the global variables to work?

EDIT:

I just went and ran a test. I created an NSString object in my View Controller's header file, and was able to successfully get it to hold data as a global variable like this:

```
_potentialFriendz = @"Steve";
```

So it must have something to do with the fact that I created my own custom class called PotentialFriend, but I still don't understand why that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't allocating and initializing an object for `potentialFriend`. Just declaring it as a property in your header doesn't instantiate an object inside of it. It is just a property that can hold an object of the specified type.

You need to do something like:

`self.potentialFriend = [[PotentialFriend alloc] init];`

in `viewDidLoad:` or at some other initialization method (like `initWithCoder:`)

In other languages, setting `potentialFriend.name` without an instantiated object would throw some kind of exception or something, but Objective-C allows sending messages to nil (you are doing the equivalent of `[potentialFriend setName:@"string"]` when you use the dot-syntax).

Comment: This worked perfectly, I've just gotten lucky with my global variables the past couple of days I guess. Thanks for the help.